# Each column of a data.frame as a factor of two levels

Tags: r, refactoring, apply

I have the following `data.frame`:

```
# Define data.frame 
  u<-data.frame(matrix(c(0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,0), nrow=3))
# Define each column as a factor with two levels 
  r <- as.data.frame(apply(u,2,function(x) factor(x, levels = c(0,1))))
```

Although I apply the factor function to each column defining the levels, the first column only presents one of them (the 0; the only value in the column) and I want it to be a factor with two levels (0 and 1).

Any idea about how to solve it?

The problem is that using `apply` function there is a problem with columns with all the same values; if I do it manually there is not any problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `lapply` instead:

```
r <- data.frame(lapply(u, function(x) factor(x, levels = c(0,1))))
```

All data frames are list of lists, so this naturally works.

`apply` works good for functions like `mean`,`sum`,`median` etc., but if you wan't to adjust the data frame you're working on, `lapply` is more suitable.